# How to Customize Angular/Bootstrap Modal Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying not to re-invent the wheel here. I was wondering if anyone is savvy enough with Angular or Bootstrap modal transitions.

I'm quite sure the modal can do more than just slide-down fadeIn. But I can't find bootstrap classes that specify any specific transition animations.

Maybe something like the transition buttons in this link:
http://anilomanwar.github.io/d3jsExperiments/ChartWheel.html

Any good input is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to get model transistion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Fizer. Evaluating now to see how well it integrates with Bootstrap/Angular.

Maybe will just refrain from using the built-in stuff if this plugin works well.

Comment: Looks like animate.css worked like a charm, Fizer. Thanks!

We just removed some bootstrap classes we had in there, replaced with the desired animate.css property, and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using animate.css, remove any bootstrap animation classes and replaced with desired animate.css property.

"You can use animate.css to get model transistion. –  Fizer Khan Jan 29 at 4:45"

Comment: I still cant get it. where can I find these bootstrap classes?